# VisualBrush using MediaElement in a Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl that converts a text to a shape. I can then Stroke it or Fill it with a Brush. When I try to use a Visual Brush with a MediaElement (video) as the Source I am running into problems. When I do it directly in the XAML as below:

```
                    <custom:ExtendedTextBlock Text="Video Filled Text" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="60">
                <custom:ExtendedTextBlock.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush>
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <MediaElement Source="assets\1267066.mp4" Width="596" Height="366" LoadedBehavior="Play" Stretch="UniformToFill" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded" MediaFailed="MediaElement_MediaFailed" MediaOpened="MediaElement_MediaOpened" />
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </custom:ExtendedTextBlock.Fill>
            </custom:ExtendedTextBlock>
```

It works great. The problem appears when I try to create a Style using the same information:

```
           <Style x:Key="VideoFill" TargetType="{x:Type custom:ExtendedTextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Fill">
            <Setter.Value>
                <VisualBrush>
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <MediaElement Source="assets/1267066.mp4" Width="596" Height="366" LoadedBehavior="Play" LoadedBehavior="Play" Stretch="UniformToFill" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded" MediaFailed="MediaElement_MediaFailed" MediaOpened="MediaElement_MediaOpened" />
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I get no fill. No MediaOpened is thrown, no MediaFailed is thrown. It just doesn't render the fill. Using this same method with a SolidColorBrush, LinearGradientBrush, ImageBrush all works perfectly. Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: Mark Feldmans answer seems to have solved it. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen all sorts of examples of MediaElement not playing nicely with other WPF components, I don't think the dev team did their integration testing quite as comprehensively with that one as perhaps they did with other things. This particular case appears to be a bug I've seen crop up a few times where an element used in a style is created and then destroyed several times during initialization. MediaElement seems to be doing some type of deferred processing, gets confused and winds up thinking that it's no longer being used. The solution, believe it or not, is to simply set `UnloadedBehavior="Play"` as well.

Personally though I tend to avoid letting the XAML framework control things like this. My own approach with MediaPlayer is to make each instance a static resource, set both `LoadedBehavior` and `UnloadedBehavior` to `"Manual"` and control playback manually with a Blend behavior containing dependency properties that I bind back to my view models. This provides all the advantages of complete code-driven control of the media element without breaking MVVM and without having to cross your fingers and hope that the framework behaves itself.