# unexplained behavior for a VisualBrush

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a VisualBrush that contains a MediaElement.  Here is the xaml:

```
<Rectangle Name="myRectangle" Grid.Row="1">
   <Rectangle.Fill>
      <VisualBrush x:Name="myVisuaBrush" Stretch="Uniform">
         <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <MediaElement Name="me_zoneOneAdvertisement" />
         </VisualBrush.Visual>
      </VisualBrush>
   </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

The video plays just fine with the c# code below:

```
this.me_zoneOneAdvertisement.Source = new Uri("C:\\a.mp4");
this.me_zoneOneAdvertisement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
this.me_zoneOneAdvertisement.Play();

ContentWindow contentWindow = new ContentWindow();
```

However, the whole point of using a MediaBrush is to extend the capability of the MediaPlayer without wasting resources.  When I try to open up a new Window and then fill an element in that window, I can see nothing in the current window where it used to work, and the new window that opens up has no content either.  Here is the code that breaks everything.  dislay1 is a rectangle, and I am trying to fill it with the visual brush.  Why would this prevent the video from playing in the original window, and why doesn't it work in the new window I just created?

```
contentWindow.display1.Fill = this.myVisuaBrush;
```

P.S. - I can get this to work if I declare the media brush as a page level resource.  Still though, I don't understand why I can't use media brush from the  body of the xaml to fill an element in another Window.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35640551/87698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN documentation of *VisualBrush* says the following:

> However, the root UIElement is essentially isolated from the rest of the system; styles, storyboards, and external layout can't permeate this boundary. Therefore, you should explicitly specify the size of the root UIElement, because its only parent is the VisualBrush and *therefore it cannot automatically size itself to the area being painted*. For more information about layout in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), see the Layout.

That means that the Visual inside the brush is isolated from the layout process. I think this causes your problems if you specify the visual inline.

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: "the Visual inside the brush is isolated from the layout process" - that makes sense.  Thanks...

Comment: I am glad that I could help you